# Does Interface Builder add elements to UITableViewCell's contentView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, interface-builder

Reading till now, I've learned that adding UI elements to UITableViewCell's contentView is a good practice. But often, I see this being done using code.
I wanted to know that if added using Interface Builder are the elements still added to contentView?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes , They are added to Cell.ContentView.

For more Info. please follow the [Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7)

Comment: plz upvote by clicking on up arrow if my answer was helpful.Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but that requires a minimum reputation of 15 :(

Comment: Ok No Prob, Glad to help you:) Now you will have max 15 reputation.

Comment: it doesn't look like this is the case anymore. When I configure a cell in Interface Builder the view is added to the UITableViewCellScrollView and not the content view. Is anyone else seeing this?

Comment: I am also seeing this. Did you find a fix for this? It seems this may be killing my constraints.

Comment: Same here. I'm having to add my top-level view as a subview to `self.contentView` in my cell's `layoutSubviews`.